# why exception.message is not in english

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I have a c# application

```
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(url, name);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            Logger.Error("Error inside DownloadFile");
            Logger.Error(e.message);
            Logger.Error(e.InnerException);
        }
```

but i get error in non readable format

> Error inside DownloadFile
> Œﬁ∑®¡¨Ω”µΩ‘∂≥Ã∑˛ŒÒ∆˜
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): ”…”⁄ƒø±Íº∆À„ª˙ª˝º´æ‹æ¯£¨Œﬁ∑®¡¨Ω”°£ 108.160.165.189:443
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
> at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

Comment: What is `Logger`?

Comment: @mjwills it is my logging method. log4net package is used for logging

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/209259/34092 work?

Comment: @mjwills no i have tried  stackoverflow.com/a/209259/34092 this but its not working.

Comment: Is the error "wrong" in the logs only? Or also in the debugger (if you view `e.message` (sic) etc)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/209259/34092 is nothing like your code above. And your code still doesn't compile.

Comment: @mjwills do you know why this socket exception occurring while WebClient.DownloadFile() methode called

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: a downloadble ur sample 'https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.msi'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307684/webclient-error-when-downloading-file-from-https-url

Comment: @mjwills thanks for the help i will check and update

Comment: I think the message is set when the exception is created. Changing the culture at a later time would not translate the message.

Comment: @JonasH do you know hot catch exception in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message in the exception is created when it's first thrown and that will be in whatever culture the code is compiled under. You cannot change this.

As this is `WebClient` the only solution is to make sure you have the English language version of .NET installed.

Comment: @ChisF thanks for the reply, Do You know why this exception occurring