# Unable to complete download using DownloadFileAsync

Tags: vb.net, webclient, system.net, downloadfileasync

I am trying to download a file using simple basic webclient instructions, however the file is not downloading completing. If I am trying to download a 10mb/100mb file, it either downloads a 7kb file or an empty file. I am just using a ProgressBar to show the download progress. Here is the code that I am using.

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents wc As New WebClient

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test"), "100mb.test")
End Sub

Private Sub wc_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles wc.DownloadFileCompleted
    ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub wc_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles wc.DownloadProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me for a 200MB file repeatedly. The issue must be elsewhere...proxy, permissions, moon phase? Sorry, no clue.

Comment: I am not sure what is not wrong here. I tried the code a different PC. Created a brand new project with nothing but the above mentioned code on another PC. Tried for an older version of .NET Framework. Still not working. Just downloads 7kb of file and then finishes. Are there any other alternative ways of testing a download/upload speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution via [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534980/why-in-my-webclient-downloadfileasync-method-downloading-an-empty-file). I just added headers to the webclient and it worked fine. Here is the code for other's reference.

```
wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)")
```

Add it before calling the DownloadFileAsync function.